# Populating Inputs Based on HTML Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, auto-populate

I know there are many questions like this one on Stack Overflow, but I am really needing something more related towards what I am doing...so that is why I am posting this question.

I have an HTML form with PHP that pulls data from an MSSQL database in order to populate a dropdown box. I want to be able to populate the contact information text boxes once I select a name from my dropdown box. So far, I have it to where, if I select a specific vendor, the vendor name gets entered automatically into the Name, Email, and Phone Number fields. However, I want to have different attributes entered into the text fields and not the vendor name itself. How could I do this?

The fields from my database with the name, email, and phone number that I want imported are named MR_POC_N, MR_POC_E, and MR_POC_P

Also the "MR_Name" that you see is the field with all names of the vendors FYI

Here is my code for the HTML dropdown:

```
<select name="vendor_dropdown" id="ven" onChange="updateinput();">
    <option value="">Choose a Vendor</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user): ?>
            <option><?php echo $user['MR_Name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Here is my Contact Info code:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Name:</td>
        <td><input class="textbox" type="text" id="name" name="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Email:</td>
        <td><input class="textbox" type="email" id="email" name="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Phone Number:</td>
        <td><input class="textbox" type="tel" id="tel" name="number"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the update input function I have in JS. I know this is off but looking for some sort of direction as I am not the best in JS:

```
function updateinput() {


    var e = document.getElementById("ven");
        var venSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

        document.getElementById("name").value=venSelected;
        document.getElementById("email").value=venSelected;
        document.getElementById("tel").value=venSelected;
    }
```

Comment: I am more than open to using that...I am not too familiar with it but if that's what it takes to get it to work, then I am all for it!

Comment: I accidentally deleted my old comment, sorry about that. To get JQuery to work, in your <head></head> tags add the following: `<script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: okay! I got that!

Comment: I've added an answer for you, let me know if it works... I haven't tested it as I had to do this quickly. I'm happy to help wherever I can

Answer (score 0):

Keep your script the same as it currently is but change your JavaScript and the dropdown. In your dropdown try doing

```
<option value = "<?=$user['MR_Name'];?>"><?php echo $user['MR_Name'];?></option>
```

You want to make what's called an AJAX request. This will allow you to go off to another page get some data in your case you would be getting some user information, and return it to the page, without the user physically changing page!

Check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) link out for more information on AJAX.

Your AJAX call will look something like this.

```
function updateinput() {
    var e = $("#ven").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "get-user-info.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {e: e},
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            var email = data[0];
            var tel = data[1];

            $("#email").val(email);
            $("#tel").val(tel);
        }
    });
}
```

This script first gets the selected value of the dropdown. Then it starts the make the AJAX call, it's like submitting a form, we are POSTING the values across to the next page. So the page the AJAX will talk to is `get-user-info.php` it's posting the values from data. The data is sending across `e` which is what the dropdown value is. On success it will then do the code underneath which is saying parse data from a PHP array to JavaScript and then it is saying email is the first value of the array and tel is the second value from the array. Then we are saying the input with ID 'email' now equals `email` from the array and the input with ID 'tel' now equals `tel` from the array.

You will now need to create a php script in the same directory called `get-user-info.php`

In this script make a call to your database where the user is the same as the selected value `e` and return a PHP array that looks like this:

`array(email, telephone)`

This is pseudo-code for your PHP script `get-user-info.php`:

```
<?php

$e = $_POST["e"];
//Do your SQL

//In the loop
$array[] = $user["email"];
$array[] = $user["tel"];

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: Okay, so I think it makes sense for the most part, however, can you explain more about how to call and get information from the database? That is what seems a bit unclear to me right now.

Comment: So in the PHP script `get-user-info.php` you need to get the user information e is whatever the <option> value is. so if each user has an ID and you set the `<option value = '$id'></option>` then the Jquery will get that value and send it to the second script. You want to use this ID to get the email and Telephone from the database.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you told me the columns didn't you. In that case, I'll amend my code. You want to do a lookup on the name. If it's not the primary key in your table you may have a problem though.

Comment: Sorry, I got pretty busy just now...but the columns i want to look up are not the primary key

Comment: Wouldn't i be able to somehow write a query that imports those columns into the script, then write the appropriate code for that?

Comment: I'm not sure of another way that isn't overly complicated